# docker-compose create and deploy image to docker.com

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx, docker

I am trying to wrap my head around Docker. For me there are still grey areas, which I have tried to research on the internet.

I'm trying to setup a Docker for an existing Laravel application.
I use Laradock (`laradock/laradock`) from GitHub (it's like Homestead but for Docker).

I use command like this:

```
docker-compose up -d nginx mysql
```

If I use `docker ps` command, I would be able to see the running containers for both MySQL and Nginx and maybe some others.

How can I take an image of docker-compose?

I have tried this

```
docker commit [container-id] username/reponame
```

An image does get created, but it's incomplete image. As I am running a whole application with MySQL, Nginx, etc..

How to take image of whole and deploy it to Docker?

All I want is that I can deploy an existing project that is using multiple containers in local to the Docker container on `docker.com`.

I'm using Docker on Windows 10.

### Update

Here is the single node i have, currently I am on free plan with docker.com and microsoft.com.

The Node with Azure Microsoft:

[image]

The Container of Laravel:

[image]

The repository on Docker I am using on container:

[image]

and finally the image link as my repository image is public:

```
https://hub.docker.com/r/pakistanihaider/pakistanihaider.me/
```

Now for some reason the image I created and I pushed to Docker is not working and site is not going live, even on localhost when I create image and I try to run image it doesn't work. But when I try `docker-compose up -d` command, everything works perfectly.

The logs I have online for my service

```
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.794183200Z /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/supervisor/options.py:296: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.794218000Z   'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.923437200Z 2017-01-02 17:56:56,923 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.923533400Z 2017-01-02 17:56:56,923 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf" during parsing
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.958072800Z 2017-01-02 17:56:56,957 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.958969800Z 2017-01-02 17:56:56,958 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:56.960595100Z 2017-01-02 17:56:56,960 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:57.968087400Z 2017-01-02 17:56:57,967 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 7
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:57.970004700Z 2017-01-02 17:56:57,969 INFO spawned: 'hhvm-fastcgi' with pid 8
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:57.971064400Z 2017-01-02 17:56:57,970 INFO spawned: 'php5-fpm' with pid 9
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:59.547596700Z 2017-01-02 17:56:59,542 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:59.547617600Z 2017-01-02 17:56:59,542 INFO success: hhvm-fastcgi entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
[pakistanihaider-1]2017-01-02T17:56:59.547623400Z 2017-01-02 17:56:59,543 INFO success: php5-fpm entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

[image]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: What does 'That how i can take an image of docker-compose.' mean? And what do you mean 'deploy it to docker??' ? It's already 'deployed' (running) to Docker. Can you elaborate a little more on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @johnharris85
In plain words sir, i have used `docker-compose.yml` file in local with laravel project, which consists of multiple services. it works great locally on docker. but how to take image to push it to the docker.com to the container?? The image i am taking is of container and 1 container only have 1 service. but how how will this work as application depends both on php and mysql?? then how to take image of complete application ??

Comment: Still doesn't really make sense, but I think I know what you're asking. You don't push applications to dockerhub, you push images. If you want to 'run' the application somewhere, you can't do that on dockerhub (or docker.com whatever you mean by that). You need to run it on a host with Docker installed (EC2 etc...) or some container runtime engine (ECS etc...). Depending on the solution you choose, you may need to fiddle with your compose file to make it work.

Comment: @johnharris85
Im sorry, if i could not explain, i m trying to say the same thing, i want to push image, but the whole image of application?? is that possible??
and those image needs to be run on container connected to azure microsoft.

Comment: I think you should read more about how to deploy containers to Azure. That's really what you want to do. Try this - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/deploying-a-2-container-application-in-azure-with-docker-compose-and-the-docker-vm-extension/

Comment: @johnharris85
Sir, i have updated my question, added screenshots of how i tried to deploy my files. 

Please take a look and see if im missing something.

Comment: `docker-compose` doesn't create an image for you it's rather a tool to run multiple containers together and set up links between them.  It does have commands which build new images if you make any changes, but it doesn't combine them into a single image. If you are making any change, then you would need to build new images and push then into your Docker repository. In order to run your newly built image in production environment you will have to modify `docker-comple.yml` to reference your images.

Comment: Very late to the party but the problem might be that laradock maps your application using a volume map, meaning that when you build the image and push it, it won't include your app